# Estimating the number of dice from an estimate of the number of 6s

Tags: probability, dice, estimation, standard-deviation, variance

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165242/estimating-the-number-of-dice-from-the-number-of-6s). The scenario is the same: Somebody rolls $n$ dice (each has $6$ sides, perfectly balanced), and counts the number of $6$s (let's call this number $X_6$). I have to estimate $n$, but this time, instead of knowing $X_6$ directly, I only know an *estimate* of $X_6$ (let's call it $\hat{X_6}$). This estimator is assumed to be non-biaised and has a constant standard error $c$.

The best estimator I can think of for $n$ is $6\cdot \hat{X_6}$. I can't manage to figure out:

1. <s>Whether the "non-biaised" property of the estimator $i\rightarrow \hat{i}$ automatically means that my estimator is not biaised.</s> Nevermind, of course it does, the expected value is linear.
2. What the standard error of my estimator is, or at least a good lower bound for it. If this is too difficult to compute, the same question with "standard error" replaced by "mean/median relative error" is also interesting to me.

(Reason for this question: in my original problem, the estimate comes from a [HyperLogLog sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog), and I'm trying to understand what would be the "cost" of computing my sketch only on a sample to estimate global cardinality.)

Comment: So random variable $\hat X_6$ is an estimator of random variable $X_6$ here? Peculiar. I am not familiar with it, but do not exclude that it concerns a part of probability theory that is not in my scope (yet). What is the criterium for $\hat X_6$ to be unbiased then? That $X_6$ and $\hat X_6$ have equal expectation maybe? And how is the constant standard error defined? Don't feel obliged to answer all my questions, but see it as a stimulus to wonder whether everything is okay here.

Comment: I have a composition of two random processes: one is a binomial process with $p=\frac{1}{6}$ and a parameter $n$, the other is a "black-box" process $f$ which transforms an integer $m$ into a complex object ($f(m)=M$). We know that there exists an estimator $\hat{m}(M)$ that estimates $m$, this estimator is not biaised (its expected value is $m$) and has a fixed standard error $\frac{1}{m}\sqrt{ \mathrm{Var}[\hat{m}]}=c$. The information I get is $M=f(X_6)$, and I'm composing the two estimators to estimate the parameter $n$. Hope that answers your questions? Sorry for my bad terminology =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, given $X_6$, $\hat{X}_6$ is a random variable sampled from a distribution with mean $X_6$ and variance $c^2X_6^2$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}(\hat{X}_6)~&=~\sum_{k=0}^n\mathsf{E}(\hat{X}_6 \mid X_6 = k)\cdot\Pr(X_6 = k) \\
&=~ \sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot \Pr(X_6 = k) \\
&=~ \mathsf{E}(X_6) = \frac{n}{6}
\end{align}
By the law of total variance, we have
\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(\hat{X}_6)~&=~\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{Var}(\hat{X}_6 \mid X_6)) + \mathsf{Var}(\mathsf{E}(\hat{X}_6 \mid X_6)) \\
&=~\mathsf{E}(c^2X_6^2) + \mathsf{Var}(X_6) \\
&=~c^2\mathsf{E}(X_6^2) + \frac{5}{36}n \\
&=~c^2(\mathsf{Var}(X_6) + \mathsf{E}(X_6)^2) + \frac{5}{36}n \\
&=~c^2(\frac{5}{36}n + \frac{1}{36}n^2) + \frac{5}{36}n
\end{align}