# Estimating sample size based on partial results?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Say I have a fair 100-sided die that I rolled an unknown number of times. I know that I rolled a 7 exactly 219 times. Intuitively, I know there were probably around 21900 rolls (since ~1% of them would be 7) - but how do I calculate a 95% confidence interval around the total number of rolls?

Comment: I am not a statistician. And thus I find it a bit perplexing to talk about confidence intervals in this way. It seems to be one step further along, after first asking "I got 219 sevens, what's the probability that I threw 21900 dice?" And I have no idea what that even means. Presumably statisticians have found a way to try to make sense of it all.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165242/estimating-the-number-of-dice-from-the-number-of-6s and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168370/estimating-the-number-of-dice-from-an-estimate-of-the-number-of-6s

Answer (score 1):

Variance $\sigma^2=.01-.0001$.  Standard deviation for a sample (no. of 7's)  of size n is $\sigma\sqrt{n}\approx 1.48$.  For 95% confidence you need approx. 2 deviations = 2.96.  Therefore your original total sample had an interval of  $\pm 219$

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is the total number of rolls, then $M = N - 219$ is the number of non-7 rolls, and $M$ is distributed as a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), so we would write $M \sim NB(219, 0.01)$.

The mean of $M$ is $\frac{219 \times 0.99}{0.01} = 21681$, and its variance is $\frac{219 \times 0.99}{0.01^2} = 2168100$, so its standard deviation is $\sqrt{2168100} \approx 1472$.

Now, since the negative binomial can be expressed as a sum of iid geometric distributions, we can apply the central limit theorem and generate a confidence interval based on approximating it as a normal distribution, which would give us a 95% confidence interval of something like $(18795, 24567)$.